# NFS - How to prevent deleting when the file is locked

Tags: java, linux, unix, nfs

I have a program that writes some state info to a file and deletes it after it is useless. To solve the process level conflict, I use the [FileChannel.lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock()) to lock the file.

It works well in most cases, but when using the NFS, I can see the file can be deleted without error even if the file is locked. The local file and SMB doesn't do this, they report an error when deleting. I tested both NFSv3 and NFSv4 both have the same behavior. The mount options are "sync,mand". Anyone can help?

I noticed the [fcntl document](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) says the "Mandatory locking is enabled on a file by disabling group execute permission on the file and enabling the set-group-ID permission bit.". But when I did that, the JDK reports the error "java.io.IOException: No locks available". Maybe I use the NFS locking in the wrong way?

Comment: File locking and NFS has always been a pretty flaky combination.

Comment: Are you saying that if you lock a file on a local Linux filesystem, and then try to delete it, the deletion fails?